# Is there a way to count the number of rows that have all the variables being searched for

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to try and count the number of rows that have the correct information in the column headings. For example, say each row is a different location, and I want to count the number of locations that have a blue roof, wooded build, located within a certain distance (say 200m - 300m) away from a structure.

I work for a train company and I'm trying to see how many defects we have in an excel spreadsheet.

Say rows F2 to F50 are different locations, J2 to J50 are reference location codes, K2 is the Track ID, and column J and M are distance information. I've been trying to use VBA to search a excel sheet and see how many rows have the correct F,J and K values I'm searching for but can't think of a way to do it. the problem is i need the number of rows that have the correct information in sequence. say row 5 has all the correct variables, so i would count row 5 in the total.

I'v explained this terribly but hope it makes a small bit of sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this have to be VBA?  This is precisely what the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) is designed to do.

Comment: i was originally trying to do a COUNTIF, but because i need to scan the whole of the second excel sheet i couldn't see how it could be done. The first Excel sheet has the variables we're looking for, then the entirety of the second sheet needs to be scanned for the correct information to see how many defects we have. Its a really hard problem.

Comment: Did you try COUNTIF**S** (and not just COUNTIF)?  COUNTIFS can do exactly what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you just need to count the number of rows where all of the conditions should be matched. Please try this code and tell me if it works for you or not:

```
Sub NewCode()

    Dim lastRow As Variant
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim counter As Integer
        counter = 0

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, "F").Value = "CORRECT VALUE 1" And _
            Cells(i, "J").Value = "CORRECT VALUE 2" And _
            Cells(i, "K").Value = "CORRECT VALUE 3" Then

            counter = counter + 1

        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "No of rows: " & counter

End Sub
```

Comment: Miras you are an absolute legend! It works perfectly. I have two columns called Start mileage and End mileage. 1 set of start and end mileage are for the length of track, and the other set is where the defect lies. is there a way to see if there is a defect in the original start and end mileage?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to add two columns, which will show you, first: the difference between End mileage and Start mileage and, second, if there is a negative difference that indicates a defect?

Comment: Is there a way to automatically grab the "ELR", "Track ID" etc from the first sheet and use the macro on the second sheet, and store the result in the appropriate cell in the first sheet.

Also i was hoping to add in other cell values that allow the cell number to be lower than or equal to that cell, but it doesn't seem to work: 

            Cells(i, "L").Value = ">=39.0200" And _
            Cells(i, "M").Value = "<=39.0210" And _



Any Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: So in a way i can narrow down the search results by seeing if the defect (the second start and end milage), is within the the bit of track i am looking at (the first start and end milage)

Comment: i was originally trying to do a COUNTIF, but because i need to scan the whole of the second excel sheet i couldn't see how it could be done. The first Excel sheet has the variables we're looking for, then the entirety of the second sheet needs to be scanned for the correct information to see how many defects we have. Its a really hard problem.